# How to Serialize SqlHierarchyId to String

Tags: c#, json

I have a table with a `SqlHierarchyId` field type.

The default JSON serialization returns a javascript object that looks like this: `{isNull: false}` instead of a string like this `/1/`

Is there some way to set the serialization properly?

```
public class MyClass
{
    [SerializeToString]
    public SqlHierarchyId NodeId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the MSDN documentation, [`SqlHierarchyId`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlhierarchyid.aspx) implements both a [`ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlhierarchyid.tostring.aspx) method and a static [`Parse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlhierarchyid.parse.aspx) method to facilitate converting it to a canonical string representation and back.  So, assuming you are using [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for serialization, you should be able to make a straightforward [`JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) class to bridge the gap.  Here is what it would look like:

```
public class SqlHierarchyIdConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(SqlHierarchyId));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        string id = (string)reader.Value;
        return (id == null || id == SqlHierarchyId.Null.ToString()) ? SqlHierarchyId.Null : SqlHierarchyId.Parse(id);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(value.ToString());
    }
}
```

To use it, you can either mark the `SqlHierarchyId` properties in your classes with a `[JsonConverter]` attribute like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(SqlHierarchyIdConverter))]
    public SqlHierarchyId NodeId { get; set; }
}
```

Or, alternatively, you can pass an instance of the converter as a parameter to [`SerializeObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeObject.htm) or [`DeserializeObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm):

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myClass, new SqlHierarchyIdConverter());
```

Here is a round-trip demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7h7E82